# AWS Amplify Cloud Logic: Access Cognito Custom Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm currently working on a multi-user / multi-organisation platform based on ReactJS and AWSMobile and following quite a bit of reading it seems to be a well guided practice to use AWS Cognito Custom Attributes to hold information in regarding to user state; for example the organisation under which they are logged in within the application.

For the Sake of Segregation and making the application more efficient I thought that using Cloud Logic (Lambda / NodeJS) - I should be able to pull down these user attributes veryify which accounts they are currently linked to and operate based on that result.

I have been trying to use `adminGetUser` on cognito unsuccessfully with each attempt giving a `ResourceNotFoundException: User pool` where I'm quite confident my pool id is correct as are the API keys and region.

I'd appreciate some pointers as I've been stuck at this for hours and there's very little I can find on how this could be potentially resolved.

Comment: If I understood you right, you are trying to run a lambda against all of the cognito users and add/update their custom attribute like `application_id`, right?

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo no all I want to do is *read* the attributes linked to that user to find for example `active_org_id` in a multi-organisation multi-user set-up. I've moved all this logic to my react application rather than lambda at this point; but I feel that it would be far more secure done in lambda.

Comment: `linked to that user` which one?